# Matrix pattern generation

Tags: java

### **Hello**

I am working on java and I have to generate all the possible patterns(combinations) of M-by-N matrices such that in the same row there should not be more than a single 1, Same column may contain more than a single 1, Taking an example of 3*3 matrix, matrices generated should look like:

```
1 0 0  
1 0 0  
1 0 0  

0 1 0  
1 0 0  
1 0 0  

0 0 1  
1 0 0  
1 0 0  

1 0 0  
0 1 0  
1 0 0  

1 0 0  
0 0 1  
1 0 0  

1 0 0  
1 0 0  
0 1 0  

1 0 0  
1 0 0  
0 0 1  

0 1 0  
0 1 0  
0 1 0  

1 0 0  
0 1 0  
0 1 0  

0 0 1  
0 1 0  
0 1 0  

0 1 0  
1 0 0  
0 1 0  

0 1 0  
0 0 1  
0 1 0
```

..... and so on.

As I have already said that progrom should be flexible that can generate all such possible patterns for any value of M and N.

Please help me..

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: 1 for loop to iterate over rows, 1 for loop to iterate over the position of the 1 in each row. It might make sense to make a Matrix class and create a list of matrices.

Comment: Does a row *have* to contain a 1?

Comment: This sounds like homework on double looping. The code is so simple that posting it on here will effectively be doing your task for you.

Comment: @Perception, a double loop? I'd be interested in such solution :-)

Comment: @aioobe - Lol ok fine, a triple loop ;). At least without using Java magics.

Comment: @aioobe..yes, a row have to cantain a 1, i have edited my question...plz..have a look :)

Comment: @prem, well then my solution should fit your needs :-)  @Perception, How's it going with your looping solution? :P

Comment: @Perception, this isn't my home work, i tried but couldn't get all the possible matrices :(

Comment: @Perception, As I see it, generating all 2-row matrices is trivial to do with 2 loops. One outer loop to iterate through all columns in the top row, and one inner loop to iterate through all columns in the lower row. For an arbitrary number of rows however, I don't think you can solve it that easily using loops. I believe you need some form of stack (either an explicit stack, or by using the call-stack as in my solution).

Comment: @aioobe,what if i have to make my code flexible..will it work fo any value of M and N??

Comment: @perm, my code works for any number of rows and columns. Just call `matrices(M, N)` for arbitrary values of `M` and `N`.

Comment: @amit...what i have tried is in question..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution. [ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/48C3x).

I bet it can be done with half the number of rows though.

```
public static Set<int[][]> chooseFrom(List<int[]> choices, int choose) {
    Set<int[][]> results = new HashSet<int[][]>();
    if (choose == 1) {
        for (int[] choice : choices)
            results.add(new int[][] { choice });
    } else {
        for (int[] choice : choices) {
            for (int[][] submatrix : chooseFrom(choices, choose - 1)) {
                int[][] matrix = new int[choose][];
                matrix[0] = choice;
                for (int r = 1; r < choose; r++)
                    matrix[r] = submatrix[r-1];
                results.add(matrix);
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}

public static Set<int[][]> matrices(int M, int N) {
    List<int[]> possibleRows = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int[] row = new int[N];
        row[i] = 1;
        possibleRows.add(row);
    }

    return chooseFrom(possibleRows, M);
}
```

**Output for the 2x3 case:**

```
[ 0 0 1 ]
[ 0 1 0 ]

[ 1 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 1 ]

[ 0 0 1 ]
[ 0 0 1 ]

[ 0 0 1 ]
[ 1 0 0 ]

[ 0 1 0 ]
[ 1 0 0 ]

[ 0 1 0 ]
[ 0 1 0 ]

[ 1 0 0 ]
[ 1 0 0 ]

[ 0 1 0 ]
[ 0 0 1 ]

[ 1 0 0 ]
[ 0 1 0 ]
```

Comment: Otherwise I wouldn't have posted it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it as three 1 dimensional arrays where there are logic checks to see if a given array is acceptable. By acceptable, I mean contains no more than a single 1. I'd then save this configuration since columns don't matter.

Once that's done with, I'd then iterate through all the possible valid array combinations and print them out using for loops for each array in question. I'd advice making a class to encapsulate each set of arrays and write some methods to traverse and print them correctly. I'd then put all of those objects in a linked list as they get generated and then traverse that list to print all of the possible options after generation.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there are per line exactly n possibilites for a 1 per row. So to enumerate all possible matrices you just loop over the col index and place a 1 in that col. As you want all rows and all combinations you have to do that now recursive for all rows, and volia: you have your solution.

(Your question does not even hint what you have already tried, nor where you get stuck, so the answer is very unspecific).

Comment: I have edited my question again..so plz see the question and suggest a working way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MatrixPatternGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int M = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                    int[] rows = new int[M];
        Arrays.fill(rows, 0);
                    System.out.println("Matrix number-> 1");
        printMatrix(M, N, rows);
        int cursor = M-1;
        while (true){
            if (rows[cursor]==N-1){
                if (cursor==0)
                    break;
                rows[cursor]=0;
                cursor--;
                continue;
            }
            rows[cursor]++;
                            printMatrix(M, N, rows);
            if (cursor<M-1){
                cursor = M-1;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void printMatrix(int M, int N, int[] rows){
                for (int i=0 ; i<M ; i++ ){
            for (int j=0 ; j<rows[i] ; j++){
                System.out.print(" 0");
            }
            System.out.print(" 1");
            for (int j=rows[i]+1 ; j<N ; j++){
                System.out.print(" 0");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm...
If i correct this is similar with permutation algorithm.
look if you have 3x3 so it's same with find a permutation of 123
so permutation will like

```
111
112
113
121
131
...etc
```

and than convert/display it like array

```
111 
will be
100
100
100

112
will be
100
100
010

... etc
```

hope this will help

Comment: As I have said in my question..the code should be flexible...In short for m*n there sould be any value of m and n :)

Comment: Yes it can. For example u want to 4x4 matrix than will be 4 digit and 4 nummber variant so like this: 1234. But if you want something like 4x5 so will be 5 digit and 4 number variant. Hope this will help